# Genetic Algorithm and neural network failing to learn

Tags: neural-network, genetic-algorithm, pybrain, evolutionary-algorithm, genetic-programming

I am trying to make a Flappy Bird AI where the agent tries to learn to pass through the pipes via genetic algorithms and neural network.

My implementation is that I am using a neural network with two inputs (horizontal distance from pipe and vertical distance from pipe opening), one hidden layer of 5 neurons, and one output layer.

The genetic algorithm evolves the agent by constantly changing one of the weights of the neural network per generation. (based on [this GA implementation](http://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2011/09/28/evolutionary-algorithm-evolving-hello-world/))

However I noticed that the flappy bird agent is failing to learn, to the point where it never even attempts to flap once (the entire time, it keeps falling at the beginning of every generation) all the way until the 485th generation (where an "maximum recursion depth exceeded" error occurs)

Genetic Algorithm + Neural Network functions:

```
def flap(playery, playerFlapAcc):

        playerVelY = playerFlapAcc
        playerFlapped = True
        if sound:
            SOUNDS['wing'].play()

        return playerVelY, playerFlapped


def mutate(n):
    global in_to_hidden
    global hidden_to_hidden2
    global hidden_to_out

    layer_select = random.uniform(0,2)

    print 'Changed:'
    if layer_select == 0:
        selector = int(random.uniform(0,5))
        print in_to_hidden.params[selector]
        in_to_hidden.params[selector] = in_to_hidden.params[selector] + random.uniform(-5,5)
        print in_to_hidden.params[selector]
    elif layer_select == 1:
        selector = int(random.uniform(0,5))
        print hidden_to_hidden.params[selector]
        hidden_to_hidden2.params[selector] = hidden_to_hidden2.params[selector] + random.uniform(-5,5)
        print hidden_to_hidden.params[selector]
    else:
        selector = int(random.uniform(0,3))
        print hidden_to_out.params[selector]
        hidden_to_out.params[selector] = hidden_to_out.params[selector] + random.uniform(-5,5)
        print hidden_to_out.params[selector]
    return n

def predict_action(rangex, error, playery, playerFlapAcc, playerVelY, playerFlapped, i):
    global jumped


    if i % 10 == 0:
        pred = n.activate([rangex, error]).argmax()
        if pred == 1:
            jumped = True
            playerVelY, playerFlapped = flap(playery, playerFlapAcc)
    return playerVelY, playerFlapped

def initalize_nn():
    global in_to_hidden
    global hidden_to_hidden2
    global hidden_to_out

    # Old code (regression)        
    n = FeedForwardNetwork()
    # n = buildNetwork( 2, 3, data.outdim, outclass=SoftmaxLayer )

    inLayer = LinearLayer(2)
    hiddenLayer = SigmoidLayer(5)
    hiddenLayer2 = SigmoidLayer(5)
    outLayer = LinearLayer(1)

    n.addInputModule(inLayer)
    n.addModule(hiddenLayer)
    n.addModule(hiddenLayer2)
    n.addOutputModule(outLayer)


    in_to_hidden = FullConnection(inLayer, hiddenLayer)
    hidden_to_hidden2 = FullConnection(hiddenLayer, hiddenLayer2)
    hidden_to_out = FullConnection(hiddenLayer2, outLayer)

    n.addConnection(in_to_hidden)
    n.addConnection(hidden_to_hidden2)
    n.addConnection(hidden_to_out)

    n.sortModules()
    return n

def fitness_fun(score, x_distance, error):
    # Fitness function was designed so that the largest distance is
    # the most fit. Before going through the first pipe, total distance traveled is the fitness. 

    # Once agent passed through the first pipe and earned a point, 
    # the amount of points it gained is the main determinant of the fitness score

    if error != 0:
        fitval = abs((100*score) + (x_distance/(2*abs(error))))
    else:
        fitval = abs(100*score) + x_distance*2
    return fitval
```

Sample implementation in the game:

```
def mainGame(movementInfo):
    global fitness
    global old_fitness
    global num_nn_parameters
    global score
    global disx
    global first_time
    global n
    global old_n
    global in_to_hidden
    global hidden_to_hidden2
    global hidden_to_out
    global generation

    global jumped


    print 'generation: ', generation

    generation = generation + 1


    if first_time:
        ### Initalizing the neural network        
        n = initalize_nn()
        ds = ClassificationDataSet(2, nb_classes=2)
        z = 0
        for val in in_to_hidden.params:

            in_to_hidden.params[z] = random.uniform(-2,2)
            z = z + 1

        num_nn_parameters = z

        old_nn = n

    else:
        # create new nn (but with old_nn saved)
        n = mutate(old_n)

        disx = 0
        score = 0

    first_time = False

    # Print weights
    print_all_weights()



    ####    

    '''
    NOTES:
    playerx = player's x position (57)
    playery = player's height
    upper_gap
    lower_gap
    center_cord


    '''
    pipeHeight = IMAGES['pipe'][0].get_height() 
    upper_gap = newPipe1[0]['y'] + pipeHeight
    lower_gap = upper_gap + PIPEGAPSIZE
    center_cord = upper_gap + ((lower_gap - upper_gap)/2)




 ###########  The main loop ###########

    #playerx = 140

    while True:
        i = i + 1
        disx = disx + 1

        # Error is determined by comparing the agent's y distance from the pipe opening
        error = playery - center_cord





        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN and (event.key == K_SPACE or event.key == K_UP):
                if playery > -2 * IMAGES['player'][0].get_height():
                    playerVelY = playerFlapAcc
                    playerFlapped = True
                    if sound:
                        SOUNDS['wing'].play()



        # check for crash here
        crashTest = checkCrash({'x': playerx, 'y': playery, 'index': playerIndex},
                               upperPipes, lowerPipes)

        if crashTest[0]:

            fitness = fitness_fun(score, disx, error)






            print '------------------- Game Over ---------------------'
            print 'fitness: [', fitness, ']'
            print 'old fit: [', old_fitness, ']'
            print ''
            print ''
            print 'error: ', error
            #print 'score: ', score
            print 'range_x', rangex
            print 'player_x: ', disx
            print '----------------------------------------------------'
            print ''
            print ''
            print ''
            print ''
            print ''


            # If it turns out the old nn was better
            if old_fitness > fitness:

                # prevents the old but good nn from being overwritten
                n = old_n
                fitness = old_fitness
            else:
                print 'Better fitness discovered'
            # store the good nn as the old_nn


            old_n = n


            old_fitness = fitness



            return {
                'y': playery,
                'groundCrash': crashTest[1],
                'basex': basex,
                'upperPipes': upperPipes,
                'lowerPipes': lowerPipes,
                'score': score,
                'playerVelY': playerVelY,
            }



        rangex = upperPipes[0]['x'] - 92



        # Make prediction
        playerVelY, playerFlapped = predict_action(rangex, error, playery, playerFlapAcc, playerVelY, playerFlapped, i)
```

Does anyone know the cause of this and how I can fix this?

Comment: [Minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please...

Comment: There, I reduced a lot of the code

Comment: Are you implementing your own learning rule?

Comment: I am not trying to. I am trying to get some sort of genetic algorithm to alter the weights of the neural network and will take anyone's implementation if it is better and solves my problem

Comment: This really looks like a "fix my code" question. Where is the genetic part? You seem to randomly mutate the weights but there doesn't seem to be any attempt to allow one configuration of weights to mix with another (mating) and there doesn't seem to be any reward for being fit. You seem to be searching the fitness space by merely examining random points. I could be wrong -- there's way too much code here.